# Reading a config.json from a nodejs discord bot

Tags: arrays, node.js, discord.js

i'm wondering if there is a other way to read my code from the config.json file ?

for example this is in my config.json

```
{
            "prefix": "!",
            "Settings":
            [
            {"bot_secret_token": "11111111111111"},
            {"PushToken": "11111111111111"},
            {"PushREF": "11111111111111"}, 
            {"Push_EventID": "11111111111111"},
            {"Home_IP": "11111111111111"},
            {"Home_port": "11111111111111"},
            {"Homes2_Port": "11111111111111"},
            {"GROUPNAME":"Settings"},
            {"OwnerID":"11111111111111"},
            {"StatusCHannelID":"11111111111111"},
            {"Channel2Way":"11111111111111"},
            {"PushAccount1":"11111111111111"},
            {"PushAccount2":"11111111111111"},
            {"GuildID":"11111111111111"},
            {"HumGroup":"11111111111111"},
]
}
```

when i want to read out for example Ownerid i need to use this code
so i always need to count the number[8]

```
let owner =  client.users.get(config.Settings[8].OwnerID);
```

is there a way to get rid of it and just do it in a better way?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
const config = require('./config');

const found = config.Settings.find((elem) => Object.keys(elem).some((key) => key == 'OwnerID'));

// found is equal to { OwnerID: '11111111111111' }
let owner = client.users.get(found.OwnerID);
```

Comment: many thanks, but sadly it doesnt work with my code..  i need to use client.users.get before it, if it only could return the 111111111111 value it maybe solve the problem

Comment: that works thanks, but can i use it for multiple items ? like key == 'OwnerID' & 'DeviceID' or do i have to create an other line for it ? regards

Comment: You could create a function from it, where the argument will be the key you are looking for.

Comment: It won't work for multiple items, I suggest you to create a function and reuse it multiple times.